# ActiveRecord exception is not throwing within Service Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In building a Service Object, the `RecordInvalid` exception is not being thrown when it should be. Instead, the code in the `else` block is run every time.

```
# services/new_registration_service.rb
class NewRegistrationService

  ...  

  def perform    
    begin
      account_create
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => exception
      OpenStruct.new(success?: false, user: user, account: account, error: exception.message)
    else
      # this is running every time
      OpenStruct.new(success?: true, user: user, account: account, error: nil)
    end
  end

  private

    ...

    def account_create
      # this is NOT saving, which I believe should
      # throw the exception in the perform method
      post_account_setup if account.save
    end

    ...

end
```

This is what I'm running from my spec, where `account: name` is required:

```
post :create, params: { account: FactoryBot.attributes_for(:account, { name: nil }) }
```

Even when I `puts` the returned `account.name` value, it's `nil`... which is what should kick the `RecordInvalid` exception.

```
# models/account.rb
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  resourcify
  has_many :users
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `account.save!` instead of `account.save`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def account_create
  # Instead of this:
  post_account_setup if account.save

  # Do this:
  account.save!
  post_account_setup
end
```

Calling `save` instead of `save!` will not raise an exception; it will just return `false`.

Alternatively, some would argue that using an exception to control flow like this is bad practice. So instead, you could do something like:

```
def perform
  # ...
  if account.valid?
    account.save! # This should never fail!
    post_account_create
    OpenStruct.new(success?: true, user: user, account: account, error: nil)
  else
    OpenStruct.new(success?: false, user: user, account: account, error: account.errors)
  end
end
```

Or, similarly:

```
def perform
  # ...
  if account.save
    post_account_create
    OpenStruct.new(success?: true, user: user, account: account, error: nil)
  else
    OpenStruct.new(success?: false, user: user, account: account, error: account.errors)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could handle this simply in one line (broken into two here for readability):

```
def perform   
  OpenStruct.new(success?: account.save, user: user, 
                 account: account, error: account.errors)
end
```

***IF*** `post_account_create` could be moved to the model, which I'd suggest would be a [more natural home for it](https://www.sitepoint.com/10-ruby-on-rails-best-practices/), i.e.

**account.rb**

```
after_create :post_account_create
```

More info on the lifecycle [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html).

`account.errors` will return an empty array if there aren't any, which shouldn't be hard to handle elsewhere based on either its emptiness or the response's success.

Hope that's useful.